# Multiply a column of a data frame into every column of a different data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to multiply a single-column data-frame into every column of another data-frame. both have 40 rows.
The idea is that the single column has calculated weights which I want to apply to the returns given in the other data frame

Here are all the ones I tried but I keep getting `NaN` values.

```
#lineaInter5m= li_wg * stocks5m
#lineaInter5m = stocks5m.mul(li_wg);
#print(li_wg.multiply(stocks5m))
#li_wg["li_wg"] * stocks5m
```

Comment: please provide the code/data **as text**, not images

Comment: From the way you describe it, it makes more sense to use numpy arrays instead, which are easier to perform broadcasting with, i.e., applying the same column operation to all rows in another array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `axis` parameter to "index" or 0

```
lineaInter5m = stocks5m.mul(li_wg, axis=0)
```